# Ruby regular expression with black list of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Let's say we have the following string:

```
form-group checkbox-group group for-group
```

How I can to replace all occurrences of `group` with the `team` using Ruby. The restriction is that I would like to have black list of patterns which shouldn't be replaced.

So for `black_list = ['checkbox-group', 'form-group']` I would like to achieve following transformed string:

```
form-group checkbox-group team for-team
```

Do you have any idea how to begin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"form-group checkbox-group group for-group"
.gsub(/(#{Regexp.union(black_list)})|group/){$1 || "team"}
# => "form-group checkbox-group team for-team"
```

Comment: could you walk us through this? I'm having trouble groking the block. I haven't seen gsub used like this before.

Comment: The regex has alternatives. The first alternative has the first capture, and the second alternatives does not have a capture. In the block, `$1` refers to the first capture, or `nil` if there isn't any.

Comment: Ah, I missed the capture! That's a great way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a regex only solution (assuming blacklist is prefix only)

```
s = 'form-group checkbox-group group for-group'
s.gsub /(?<!checkbox-|form-)group/, 'team'
```

[Link to rubular to fiddle around.](http://rubular.com/r/qLTo12LYQl)

Comment: Another problem is that the OP showed the array `black_list`, but you haven't shown how to convert that into what you have.